# Find out what Data Security Profiles look like

Tags: business-objects, row-level-security, data-security

A colleague has left the company.
We know she implemented Data Security Profiles in our SAP BO 4.1 (unx universes)
She somehow implemented row-level security.
We do not know how. There are questions now how this row-level security is working.
To understand what's happening I need to see what these profiles look like.
However, when I am going to the security editor I cannot edit Data Security Profiles, I can only insert them.

How can I find out how she configured row-level security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be found in SAP BO manuals (blush)